# ASP.NET MVC 3 RedirectToRouteResult

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

`RedirectToRouteResult` does not redirect to the specified controller-action pair.

```
public class CustAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
  ...
  public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
  {
     base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
     ...
     if (...) {
        var routeDictionary = new RouteValueDictionary { { "action", "Forbidden" }, { "controller", "Error" } };
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(routeDictionary);                    
     }
  }
}
```

Please, help.

Comment: Where does it route to?  Do you have any special routes setup?  What does your routing rule look like?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could try something like:

```
UrlHelper urlHelper = new UrlHelper(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RequestContext);
filterContext.Result = urlHelper.Action("Forbidden" , "Error");
```